# Adding a Class from a Div

Tags: jquery

A user can "add" or "delete" users via 2 buttons from a list on a page.

I need to hide the delete button sometimes. To do so, I'd like to add the class `disabled`.

However, it's possible that, sometimes, the button will already be disabled.

Is it bad practice to add a class to a jQuery object that it may already have? How about removing a class that it may not have?

HTML

`<div class="button delete-button"></div>`

Disabled:

`<div class="button delete-button disabled"></div>`

Comment: It's fine practice.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that. jQuery is written to handle it.

Comment: if it already has the class it wont add it again, so it wont have like class="disabled disabled", same with the remove, it wont remove it if it doesnt exist

Comment: Have you tried to jQuery functions like addClass() and removeClass()?

Comment: What? Why add a class to something that already has it. Just because it works doesn't mean it semantically makes sense. Use a selector to filter elements which don't have it first.

Comment: Nope, no disabled disabled

Comment: I think one of the reasons for `addClass()` and `removeClass()` was that you do not have to check - it's done for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Is it bad practice to add a class to a jQuery object that it may already have? How about removing a class that it may not have?`

with jQuery .addClass() you do not add existing class second time.

`Is it bad practice to add a class to a jQuery object that it may already have? How about removing a class that it may not have?`

No